# Glitchy screen when using DVI and main user

Tags: display, monitor, dvi

I recently got a new ASUS monitor, but I have a big issue when trying to get past the login screen. When using the HDMI cord this does not happen. When using the DVI I am able to see the login screen and login as a guest user and have a crisp beautiful output, but when I log in as myself as the main user I get this screen  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSyD4.jpg

I am using a 750ti graphics card and ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I cannot access the terminal when using the main account. Any ideas to fix this other than reinstall a different OS would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: Take your time reading this first sentence:

Before typing the following keystroke, remember that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> *is your friend*.  This is the keystroke to type to get back to where you are right now.  (probably your guest session) OK? Remember? Sure?

OK! Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to TTY1, which is a full screen terminal (and only a terminal: no mouse, no dash, no nothing).  Try to log in there.

It *does* show your user name when you type it after the `login:` prompt, but does not show anything when you type your password!  Oh, and you have to type <kbd>Enter</kbd> after you typed your user name and before it shows you the password prompt.

Now type the following commands: (assuming "jam" is your old user name)

```
sudo adduser jam2
```

and follow the instructions on-screen.  If you're *not on a US keyboard*, don't use any "special" characters like £ à ŷ ü nor any numbers unless they're from your keypad.

Now type the following commands:

```
sudo adduser jam2 adm 
sudo adduser jam2 cdrom
sudo adduser jam2 sudo
sudo adduser jam2 dip
sudo adduser jam2 plugdev
sudo adduser jam2 lpadmin
sudo adduser jam2 sambashare
```

(If any of the above gives an error like `group not found`, don't worry: I'm trying to be thorough)

Now, log out of the guest session and log in as "jam2" and come back here to this site and "accept" the answer by clicking on the little grey check-mark below the "0" to the left of this answer, thereby accepting the answer as valid and the next person asking the same kind of question will be able to use it as well.

Done?  OK?

Now,

1. open the file manager
2. browse to the `/home/jam` directory
3. **copy** (not move!) all the *files* from Downloads to `/home/jam2/Downloads`
4. check you did a good job.
5. Now delete `/home/jam/Downloads`
6. Go back to step 3 and repeat for Documents, Videos, ...

## Done!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed Reply. However, when I try and access the tty1 all I get is a blank black screen with no text at all.

Comment: I also plugged in my hdmi cord and did the same thing that was stated created a new user and did all those commands with no errors. After that I tried to copy the files in my directories and got got an error saying I did not have permissions to create the files in jam2

Comment: I decided to see if the new user would work, but I still get the same issue as before

Comment: So you *don't have the problem in the guest session* but you *do in this new user's session?* Until what step number did you follow the advice?

Comment: yup that seems to be the issue. Well I couldnt follow the step using the only terminal screen. So instead I used an hdmi cord which works to run the list of commands. I then switched over to the dvi cord and the same error continued with the new user.

Comment: How do you want to continue?  Shall I delete my answer? (as it's invalid for you anyway?)